# Highstock range selector custom button not working

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to add two more button to the default list of range selectors in Highstocks. 
I'm using this as the range selector options:

```
rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 5,
                        text: '5d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'ytd',
                        text: 'YTD'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                selected: null
            },
```

The default buttons works properly but the 1d and the 5d button doesn't work. For data i'm sending this `http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?` from the server and also appending the array with 5 day data in similar timestamp format. But its not working. The chart is displaying all the data at once. I mean its drawing multiple lines for the data, and in the range-selector button only 'All' can be selected, while the rest are getting disabled.

What data format should be send to the chart engine so that it can also render intraday data along with monthly and yearly data. I wanted to build an interactive chart similar to Yahoo finance charts `http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AC-A.TO+Interactive#symbol=AC-A.TO;range=1d`. But can't make the 1d and 5d options work.

Does anyone knows a way to do this?

Also i've tried to set the events.setExtreme object for the x axis. Here is the code which i copied from a jsFiddle example

```
xAxis: {
                events: {
                    setExtremes: function(e) {
                        if (typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
                            var c = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;
                            var t = e.rangeSelectorButton.type;
                            var txt = e.rangeSelectorButton.text;
                            var btn_index = null;
                            if (c == 1 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 0;
                            } else if (c == 3 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 1;
                            } else if (c == 6 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 2;
                            } else if (t == "ytd") {
                                btn_index = 3;
                            } else if (c == 0 && txt == "1d") {
                                btn_index = 4;
                            } else if (c == 0 && txt == "5d") {
                                btn_index = 5;
                            } else if (c == 1 && t == "year") {
                                btn_index = 6;

                            } else if (t == "all") {
                                btn_index = 7;
                            }
                            // Store btn_index in a cookie here and use it
                            // to initialise rangeSelector -> selected next
                            // time the chart is loaded
                            alert(btn_index);

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

I tried getting the buttons to work using the above option. But the problem is, like i mentioned above, either the 1d or the 5d buttons are disabled,   or if somehow it gets selected, it stays selected even if other buttons are clicked,  in which case its supposed to get deselected.

Unfortunately i can't set up a live jsFiddle example, because the data is being retrieved from my local PHP server, and the JSONP server which the examples in Highcharts.com site uses `http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?` doesn't have the intraday or 5 day data in it.

Here is the jquery code

```
function renderChart() {

$.ajax({
    url: $('#chart-action-path').text(),
    data: {
        range: "5y",
        name: $('#symbol-name').text()
    },
    type: "POST",
    error: function(xhr, tStatus, e) {
        if (!xhr) {
            alert(" We have an error ");
            alert(tStatus + "   " + e.message);
        } else {
            alert("else: " + e.message); // the great unknown
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);


        var options = {chart: {
                renderTo: 'info'
            },
            xAxis: {
                events: {
                    setExtremes: function(e) {
                        if (typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
                            var c = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;
                            var t = e.rangeSelectorButton.type;
                            var txt = e.rangeSelectorButton.text;
                            var btn_index = null;
                            if (c == 1 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 0;
                            } else if (c == 3 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 1;
                            } else if (c == 6 && t == "month") {
                                btn_index = 2;
                            } else if (t == "ytd") {
                                btn_index = 3;
                            } else if (c == 0 && txt == "1d") {
                                btn_index = 4;
                            } else if (c == 0 && txt == "5d") {
                                btn_index = 5;
                            } else if (c == 1 && t == "year") {
                                btn_index = 6;

                            } else if (t == "all") {
                                btn_index = 7;
                            }
                            // Store btn_index in a cookie here and use it
                            // to initialise rangeSelector -> selected next
                            // time the chart is loaded
                            alert(btn_index);
                            console.log(e.rangeSelectorButton);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'ytd',
                        text: 'YTD'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                selected: null
            },
            title: {
                text: $('#symbol-name').text() + " Stock Price",
            },
            series: [{
                    name: $('#symbol-name').text() + "Stock Trends",
                    data: JSON.parse(data), // predefined JavaScript array
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
        }



        chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);

        console.log(chart1.series);


    }
})
```

}

I hope my problem makes sense. Please provide any sort of help, its been over 2 days and i still haven't found a viable solution to this problem. Let me know if i need to provide more information.

Thanks, in advance,
Maxx

Comment: This 'disabled' state for buttons was implemented as fix for [that report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2050). Feel free to add comment there.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing me to that git report. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading seems useful, i will try implementing the demo in my project and see if i can get it working